# Is it possible to use a local HTML file using Go and webview?

Tags: html, go, webview

I want to build an application using Go with a GUI baked in. A workable solution for that seems to be webview.

What I have now is this (and it works!):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/webview/webview"
)

var count int = 0

func main() {
    w := webview.New(true)
    defer w.Destroy()

    w.SetSize(600, 200, webview.HintNone)

    w.Bind("btn", func() int {
        count++
        return count
    })

    //Create UI with data URI
    w.Navigate(`data:text/html,
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    ...
    </html>`)

    w.Run()
}
```

What I would like to do is to build the gui in a seperate workspace so that I have working syntax hilighting, intellisense etc. so something like:

```
w.Navigate("./GUI/gui.html")
```

However, I can't get it to work. is it possible anyway?

Comment: What happens if you try a [file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)?

Comment: If the file URI doesn't work you can always just open the file with `os.Open`, read its contents into a byte slice, convert that into a string, prefix the string with `data:text/html,`, and then pass the result of all that to Navigate.

Comment: "I can't get it to work" -- What happens when you try? What did you try? Include your code, and include the error message or other unexpected behavior you observed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. A file URI doesn't seem to work (I tried several options. Forward slashes, backwards slashes absolute, relative paths, absolute paths. but didn't get it to work. However the second provided solution is working. But I loose my bindings. I guess it just cannot work the way I want it to;)

Comment: @PetitBateau It seems people are using [file URIs](https://github.com/webview/webview/issues/203) already. Maybe you did something wrong.

Comment: @Flimzy In the meanwhile, the answer from Christian solved my issue.
What i tried was the following:
 w.Navigate("file:///C:/somepath/GUI/gui.html")
 w.Navigate("file://C:/somepath/GUI/gui.html")
 w.Navigate("file:\\C:\\somepath\\GUI\\gui.html")
There was no error messages, executable immediately closed after opening

Comment: @super. file URLs as a thing do work in Go. However Webview does'nt seem to accept them. Also not like this (taking into account Christian's answer):
w.Navigate(`data:text/html,` + "file:///C:/somepath/GUI/gui.html")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update: use `file:///`

Using the full path to the file.

```golang
w.Navigate("file:////Users/myuser/tempgo/hi.html")
```

#### Or read the file into memory

Use `ioutil.ReadFile` to read in the data from an HTML file. This can then be converted to a string.

```golang
file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("hi.html")
stringFile := string(file)
w.Navigate(`data:text/html,` + stringFile)
```

#### Full working example

Original code from the question.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/webview/webview"
    "io/ioutil"
)

var count int = 0

func main() {
    w := webview.New(true)
    defer w.Destroy()

    w.SetSize(600, 200, webview.HintNone)

    w.Bind("btn", func() int {
        count++
        return count
    })

    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("hi.html")

    stringFile := string(file)

    //Create UI with data URI
    w.Navigate(`data:text/html,` + stringFile)

    w.Run()
}
```

Directory structure:

```
main.go
hi.html
```

Comment: do you know why the following actually does work?
w.Navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme")

Comment: It looks like URLs are supported `// Navigate navigates webview to the given URL. URL may be a data URI, i.e.
 // "data:text/text,<html>...</html>". It is often ok not to url-encode it
 // properly, webview will re-encode it for you.
 Navigate(url string)` if you look at the source of the package. As to why, I am not sure, since the entire package is just a wrapper around some C stuff. If you "served" the static pages via a go handler/server, you could use `w.Navigate("localhost/yourPage.html")`

Comment: Yes, I did read that. But then I'm still wondering why it doesn't accept a local URL string ending with .html
As a test I also tried to host a local webserver with the html file on it, and use that URL. But with the same result

Comment: The local file path isn't a 'url' per se, it's a file:///  Which does work too. See updated answer.

Comment: Just saw you are on Windows, looks like others are having this issue too: https://github.com/webview/webview/issues/436

Comment: indeed! thanks for bringing that up. For now I'll stick to the ReadFile method :)